# Why does my fan switch sometimes turn the lights off?

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

I recently undertook a small project replacing a single toggle light switch with a Z-wave enabled dimmer switch, which is also wired to a fan toggle (a knob with 3 speed settings) in a 2-gang case. The original switch and the fan toggle share a hot wire, which I had to cut and splice due to the way the builder had installed it originally (it was just a loop of exposed wire which wrapped around one of the switch's poles). Everything went pretty well (aside from the dimmable CFLs not being as awesome as I would like, but that's tangental), but sometimes when I turn the fan to a different speed, the lights will turn off, but the switch still has power as evidenced by the blue LED at the bottom.

Now, I've done a small bit of experimentation, and this seems to only happen if you turn change the switch rapidly from one speed to another. If you wait about 20-30 seconds between switches, it doesn't do it.

What could be wrong here?

Edit: More Relevant information. The Z-Wave dimmer is rather sensitive, so if it were to lose power for any period of time it would reset to off, which is probably what is happening here.

**Diagrams**

Pardon my poor diagramming skills, I was never any good at cad.

**Before**

As you can see, the bottom wire was just wrapped around the bottom pole of the toggle switch, then ran into a wire cap, where it was connected with the fan toggle.
[image: Before]

**After**

So, I cut the loop, and then twisted it together to splice the two wires together, so that I could also splice in the wire coming from the Z-Wave switch.

[image: After]

**Edit**

**Annotated Picture**
[image: Box]

So here's what's going on in there.

Also, I took some voltage readings. When the Light is off, it is measuring 83v (which I think is normal for a Z-Wave switch, to power its wifi).
When the light is all the way on, it reads 13v.

When the fan is off, it is at 122v. On speed setting 1, it is 115v. On 2, 100v. On 3, I can't get a reading at all.

Comment: wow - in all my years of building DIY i never heard of something like that.. must be something in the middle causing a problem. can you post a picture of the wirigin? or make diagram.. there must be something wrong there. Is there voltage on the light when it 'goes off' Be careful as it could electrocute you (it might have a lower voltage, or a voltage leak) Make sure you have somebody with you just in case.

Comment: Is it 2 independent switches, or a single unit that controls both the light and the fan?

Comment: @ppumkin I have not yet tried checking the voltage while it cuts off, because I was a bit afraid of the electrocution bit. But sure, I can make you a diagram, and get you a picture of the current situation later today.

Comment: @Tester101 It is 2 switches, one controlling the lights, the second controlling the fan.

Comment: I've added a couple of diagrams, hopefully this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: emm i kinda understand it. The black/red wire is for the ligh. NOw the blue wire is live for the controller. Out of that controller must come out a seperate new wire and go to the fan motor. The fan motor and light MUST use the same BLACK(negative) the light (red only) the motoro(new wire from zwave controller)

Comment: Right, I left off the other wires for the fan, because I didn't modify them at all. The Red wire in the diagram is Red coming out of the box. The Blue wire in the diagram is black out of the box, and is connected to both the fan and the light. The blue wire is now actually 3 wires spliced together. 1 coming from the Light controller, 1 going to the fan, and 1 coming from the wall.

Comment: It would be useful to see all the wires, labelled with where they're going. I'm tempted right now to say that probably the dimmer is sensitive to electrical noise generated by the fan motor or switch, but without seeing the full wiring diagram I can't rule out a cross connection between something.

Comment: When the lights turn off, how do you get them to come back on?

Comment: @gregmac Right-o. I'll see if I can get you an actual picture when I'm back there. But as you say that is my suspicion as well, that the fan is drawing more power when the switch is turned and screwing with the dimmer. I'll also practice making not crappy diagrams.

Comment: @Tester101 - You can just switch the lights back on.

Comment: Sounds like the dimmer has some type of protection circuitry that is tripping. Do you know the model number, or make/model?

Comment: @Tester101 Sure, it's this switch: http://www.amazon.com/45606-Z-Wave-Technology-Dimmer-Switch/dp/B0013V3C4Q/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1313609437&sr=8-3

Comment: Where is the 83v and 12v measurements coming from (what two contacts)? Also, it looks like "power to fan" and "power to dimmer" marettes are redundant - there is just a small pigtail going to the incoming power line. Lose the pigtails, just use one marette - less to go wrong, and more space in the box.

Comment: @gregmac The measurements are coming from "Power to dimmer" and "to light", aka on either side of the dimmer switch. Cool deal on that, I wasn't sure if it was totally necessary to pigtail the #12 cable to each connection or just run it directly off of the power line.

Comment: Cthos- Ah, okay, then what you're measuring is incorrect. You're measuring a difference coming through somewhere else that my brain is not in the right mode to figure out right now. What you should be measuring is the voltage between "to light" and neutral, or "to fan" and neutral -- though I don't think that will help in this situation anyway.

Comment: @gregmac Since there's not an accessible neutral wire in that box, where would I place the second connection? (Pardon the noob question). But I agree, I'm beginning to think I'll just have to live with the lights occasionally going off (It now only happens when you switch from 3 to anything else, after I changed the bulbs...)

Comment: @Cthos: I see a bunch of neutral wires in the back? Anyway, for testing purposes, you can use ground instead of neutral.  (neutral and ground are bonded at your panel, which is why this works. Note though, NEVER use ground in place of neutral in wiring -- it is a code violation, fire risk, and a shock hazard).

Comment: @gregmac Yep, had seen that warning before (in big bold letters no less), which led to the question. The reason I mean they're inaccessable is that that whole thing is a painted over clump in the back, and I didn't really want to mess with digging it out.

Comment: @Cthos: You marked an answer, what ended up being the actual problem?

Comment: Marked it from my phone, waited until I got back to a computer for the typing. It was the z-wave dimmer is sensitive to the fan switch, coupled with using bulbs it wasn't happy with. I switched them to LEDs and it's mostly gone away, but I'm planning on living with the remaining problem for now, since I rarely if ever change the fan from 3 to off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wiring looks okay (except for the redundant "power to dimmer" and "power to fan" wires -- as I commented, you don't need the extra pigtails, just connect the switches directly with one marette).

I can think of 3 possibilities:

- The z-wave dimmer is not operating properly with the CFL. Try using a regular incandescent or halogen bulb, and see if the problem goes away.
- The z-wave dimmer is being affected by the electrical/RF noise that the fan generates when it turns on. Ensure the fan switch is designed to handle inductive loads, or try replacing it with another brand of switch.
- The z-wave dimmer is defective.

Answer (score 2):

If you have separate cables leading to the fan and light, you'll want to end up with something like figure 1 below.  More likely the fan and light are one unit, and there is 3 wire cable running to it from the switch. In this situation, you want to end up with figure 2 below.

[image]

Once that is sorted out, you can start to diagnose your problem.

It may be possible that the dimmer has a protection circuit to protect it from voltage fluctuations, or some other internal circuitry that is sensitive to voltage fluctuations. If this is the case, rapidly changing the fan speed may be just enough to mess with it. This might be especially evident when going from [fan off] to [fan high], as motors tend to draw more power than other fixtures especially when starting.

Comment: It is the latter situation, and the current configuration looks like Figure 2.